# Strange behavior (duplicate fire) of Firefox focus javascript-event

Tags: javascript, firefox, focus

Firefox fires focus-events on links (Opera does as well). When I tried to attach a handler to link to prevent it from gaining focus and instead pass the focus to neighbor input field something strange have happened. Firefox fires focus event two times, whereas Opera does this only once. May be it is somehow linked to capturing and bubble phases of a js-events, but I'm not sure, cause in both cases .eventPhase-property of jQuery event obj equals 2, i.e. bubble.

There is a test-page below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Text1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="click">click</a>
    <input type="text" id="to_pass">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 1;
        document.getElementById('click').onfocus = function() {
            console.log(i);
            i += 1;
            document.getElementById('to_pass').focus();
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When click occurs there is a call-count is echoed into console.

Comment: Why do you put your scripts inside CDATA? HTML5 is not XML!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, use `click()` instead of `focus()`:

```
var i = 1;
$('#click').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log(i);
    $('#to_pass').focus();
    i += 1;
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/UH5Ke/)

Comment: My appreciation, but I need to use exactly a focus, cause my intention is to prevent link from gaining focus in all cases including use of "tab" key. Actually it is not the problem, cause I solved it in another way. But when I looked for solution I've encountered that strange thing. So it's interesting to me to understand what is happening in that exact case, rather that change focus to click